# Compacting control blocks Java

Tags: java

I am wondering if I can compact my if control blocks from this:

```
    //HUNGER
    if(hungerLvl > 0){
        hunger = "Peckish";
    }
    if(hungerLvl > 50){
        hunger = "Very Hungry";
    }
    if(hungerLvl > 80) {
        hunger = "Starving";
    }
```

To something like this:

```
if(hungerLvl > 0; hungerLvl > 50; hungerLvl > 80) {

    }
```

Comment: Regarding, `"I'm wondering if I can compact my if loops..."` Note that there's not one loop in your posted code. If blocks are control blocks, not loops. Yes, I'm being pedantic, but understand that programming is an exercise in precision, and that the Java compiler and JVM are not forgiving of careless errors, and neither should you.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achive? r u trying to merge all conditions? every condition needs different actions right?

Comment: and the code seems fishy as it fill fire on the `Peckish` only for `hungerLvl > 0`.  anyway, perhaps you're looking for [`switch-case`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: You could use an array and a loop, but I think there are more efficient ways to achieve it

Comment: Yes, there's a way of doing it.  But why would you want to?  Your first code snippet seems perfectly readable to me.

Comment: I just thought it would be better to condense the code rather than having 5 blocks I can have it in one. Wouldn't it also increase the speed of the program?

Comment: Is it taking too long to execute? What are your time requirements?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely to increase the speed of your program.  It'll just make it harder to read.  Seriously, you have better ways of spending your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a big fan of using data structures+loops rather than repetitive code.  That said, this can add complexity that sometimes isn't worth it.

What you've posted looks easy to read and so it's probably not worth fussing over.  However, if you might instead end up with dozens or hundreds of conditions, then a data structure+loop will serve you better.

Here's an complete working example, using your same values.  The key method `howHungry` is neither more compact nor more readable than your 3 range example.  But, if you go to 10 or 20 conditions, then this, IMHO, will be more maintainable and more readable.

```
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HowHungry {

    public String howHungry(Integer hunger) {
        SortedMap<Integer, String> HungerLevels = new TreeMap<>();
        HungerLevels.put(0, "Peckish");
        HungerLevels.put(50, "Very Hungry");
        HungerLevels.put(80, "Starving");

        String howHungry = null;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> me : HungerLevels.entrySet() ) {
            if (hunger > me.getKey()) {
                howHungry = me.getValue();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return howHungry;
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        HowHungry hh = new HowHungry();
        System.out.println(hh.howHungry(Integer.valueOf(args[0])));
    }
}
```

Comment: No!  If you're going to go to the trouble of putting the values in a `TreeMap`, at least use the `floorEntry` method, instead of that loop.  Like `return hungerLevels.floorEntry(hunger).getValue();` instead of the nine lines you've written that are (more or less) equivalent to this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways other than plain old 'if' - but most of them still make use of it under the hood (if you like you can google for example [chain of responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) ) but in your case it would be only over-complicating and you would have to write much more, and less readable code. 
So I think in this particular case 'if' statements are the way to go.

If you are concerned about speed, then probably you should look at how many times you are doing variable assignment (it could matter if you are checking hungerLvl frequently):

```
    //HUNGER
if(hungerLvl > 0){
    hunger = "Peckish";
}
if(hungerLvl > 50){
    hunger = "Very Hungry";
}
if(hungerLvl > 80){
    hunger = "Starving";
}
```

In your code, every value check is performed regardless of the outcome of previous ones. So if hungerLvl equals for example 92, then firstly check for hungerLvl > 0 will take place and then hunger would be assigned value of "Peckish", then it would be checking next if statement, make next assignment and only then it would finally check for the greatest value and make final assignment.
So you have three assignments instead of only the final one.

In order to prevent this, you can use 'if else' block and slightly change logical expressions (I assume hungerLvl can't be lower than 0 - if it can and it would make some difference you would have to add additional check at the beggining):

```
if(hungerLvl <= 50){
    hunger = "Peckish";
} else
if(hungerLvl <= 80){
    hunger = "Very Hungry";
} else
{
    hunger = "Starving";
}
```

Notice that now if the first statement is true, everything after 'else' in the 'if else' block would be just ignored. Also, if value of hungerLvl is greater, for example 92, then it would perform checks for lower values, but no assignments would be made as checks would return false.

Bonus point is that if value isn't lower than 50 nor 80, then we don't have to check if it is higher, so we have one if statement less.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like that:

```
hunger = hungerLvl > 80 ? "Starving"
        : hungerLvl > 50 ? "Very Hungry"
        : hungerLvl > 0 ? "Peckish"
        : hunger; // or null, or whatever
```

Comment: You could but please don't.